# How to detect the end of the loop (for each)?

Tags: java, for-loop

Using `for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++)` I can easily detect if the loop is at the end.

But I how can I know if I'm using `for` or `for each`.

```
for(String str : arrayString){

    if(End of for) //Do something if the end of the loop

}
```

The reason I use `for(:)` instead of `for(;;)` is that `str` is actually a  large Object which I need to use that property for another loop inside that loop. And I don't like using much `object.get(index).getProperty` It just also for convenience to me in doing the coding. That's why I want to know if the `for(:)` loop is at the last index.

**UPDATE**

My interim solution is to assign a `int` variable that will hold the number of iteration. Then check if the variable is equal to the length of the `str.length`.

Comment: This is often a case where a standard for loop is used instead of a foreach.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: I'm aware of that, but if there's just a simple method to know at the end. It would be a great help. Like using `resultSet.next();` there is a `resultSet.isLast()`. I'm looking for that kind of method, if it is also available in `foreach`.

Comment: That sort of method is usually available on the iterator (something like `hasNext`). The whole point of the for each loop is to abstract away the iterator; unfortunately, this also means you have slightly reduced functionality.

Comment: `str.length` is not the proper length that you are looking for. It should be `arrayString.length`.

Comment: @pickypg: I know it just a sample code. My actual code is far complicated than that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option would be to write your own iterator implementation which exposed, at each point, properties of first, last, index and value.

I've done the [same thing for .NET](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/smartenumerable.html), and it was far from tricky. In Java it would be even easier, as you could use the `hasNext()` method of the original iterator to determine whether or not it's the last element. The code would look *something* like this (completely untested):

```
public SmartIterable<T> implements Iterable<SmartIterator<T>.Entry>
{
    private final Iterable<T> iterable;

    public SmartIterable(Iterable<T> iterable)
    {
        this.iterable = iterable;
    }

    public Iterator<T> iterator()
    {
        return new SmartIterator<T>(iterable.iterator());
    }
}

public SmartIterator<T> implements Iterator<SmartIterator<T>.Entry>
{
    private final Iterator<T> iterator;
    private int index = -1;

    SmartIterator(Iterator<T> iterator)
    {
        this.iterator = iterator;
    }

    public void remove()
    {
        // Could potentially just delegate
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        return iterator.hasNext();
    }

    public Entry next()
    {
        T nextValue = iterator.next();
        index++;
        return new Entry(nextValue, index);
    }

    public class Entry
    {
        private final int index;
        private final T value;

        private Entry(int index, T value)
        {
            this.index = index;
            this.value = value;
        }

        public T getValue()
        {
            return value;
        }

        public int getIndex()
        {
            return index;
        }

        public boolean isFirst()
        {
            return index == 0;
        }

        public boolean isLast()
        {
            // Call into containing instance
            return !hasNext();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir, I'm still not proficient in Java writing my own iterator could affect the performance of my application, but I'll if a have more time. As of now if there is no other way, the pickypg posted is my current solution. I'm just wondering which would be faster, the loop have about hundred thousand of iteration on the main loop. Then another hundred loop in the sub loop. If you can suggest which way is faster, its a big thanks.

Comment: @ace: Using a straight for loop would be more efficient, but possibly less elegant. But you should generally be more concerned with writing maintainable code and then *measure* the performance, rather than guessing where your bottlenecks are.

Comment: I'am more concerned with maintainable code that's why I'm looking for another way to check that last index of the loop. But I'm not still good at it, anyway I'll keep your solution then if I have more time I'm going to use it. Thanks

Answer (score 29):

Two easy ways, which are somewhat amusing given your reasoning for using the foreach loop.

```
int i = 1;
for (String str : arrayString) {
    if (i++ == arrayString.length) {
        // end
    }
}
```

Or

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayString.length; ++i) {
    String str = arrayString[i];
    if (i + 1 == arrayString.length) {
        // end
    }
}
```

Effectively the same thing. Just note the difference between the use of `i` within the `if` between the two loops and the starting value of `i`.

Comment: Thanks: your first solution is my interim solution for now. And the second solution is the one I'm trying to avoid in my current code. If no other way than the first solution, I'm going to use it.

Comment: @Jigar Fair enough, but it wasn't when I posted it. @ace As noted by Tikhon, you can use an `Iterator` for your collection, but I assumed that was not valid since you showed an array up top.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for the same in kotlin, my answer is for you :

```
for(str in arrayListString){

if(str == arrayListString.last()){
    //Do something if the end of the loop
}}
```